# Adding new dimentions to NP array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, neural-network

I was trying to understand why do we add new dimention to our array?

```
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
```

This insert a new axis to array of x. What is the purpose of it?

Comment: Who's the `we` and how's this array being defined or used?  How much of the basic `numpy` documentation have you read?

Comment: Good questions. We indicates humans :). It does not matter how it is used. The question is why? What happens when we add new axis to our array ? Btw i am working on neural network if you wonder

Comment: Under the covers all `expend_dims` does is a `np.reshape`.  As long as the total number of elements doesn't change, `rshape` can add (or remove) dimensions, including size 1's.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of when *expand_dims* can be needed:

We have 2 arrays:

```
a1 = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
a2 = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
```

Even though *a1* is a **2-D** array and *a2* is a **1-D** array,
it is possible to add them:

```
a1 + a2
```

yields:

```
array([[11, 22, 33, 44, 55],
       [16, 27, 38, 49, 60],
       [21, 32, 43, 54, 65],
       [26, 37, 48, 59, 70]])
```

i.e. consecutive elements of *a2* are added to consecutive columns
in *a1* (there are 5 elements in *a2* and 5 columns in *a1*).

But if you have another array:

```
a3 = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])
```

and you want to add each element of *a3* to each **row** in *a1* and
you attempt to run:

```
a1 + a3
```

you will get *ValueError* exception.

To successfully perform this operation, *a3* must be a **columnar** array,
i.e.:

- it must have 2 dimensions,
- it must have the same number of rows as *a1*,
- and a single column.

So, you can run:

```
a1 + np.expand_dims(a3, axis=1)
```

getting:

```
array([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
       [41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
       [56, 57, 58, 59, 60]])
```